# ESLint "Fix" button for lint errors in Atom stopped working

Tags: atom-editor, eslint

I'm using Atom with ESLint and all of a sudden I can't hover over the the indicator next to the line number and click the fix button. I get this error message every time:

```
"Failed to apply fix. Try saving to get fresh results and then try again."
```

I see the same results across multiple projects even. Any ideas what happened or how to fix this? The console just show the same message as the warning popup.

[image: linter error screenshot]

Comment: Same problem here. I'd love a fix. I'm going to try something, if it works I'll post my answer